# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' - ios - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

What is the solution to this error? I tried what I found, but I could not sort out my problem.

Error is here:

```
if var post = currentData.value as? [String : Any], let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
```

Full Code:

```
func incrementLikes(postId: String, onSucess: @escaping (Post) -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
        let postRef = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.child(postId)
        postRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
            if var post = currentData.value as? [String : Any], let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                var likes: Dictionary<String, Bool>
                likes = post["likes"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
                var likeCount = post["likeCount"] as? Int ?? 0
                if let _ = likes[uid] {
                    likeCount -= 1
                    likes.removeValue(forKey: uid)
                } else {
                    likeCount += 1
                    likes[uid] = true
                }
                post["likeCount"] = likeCount as AnyObject?
                post["likes"] = likes as AnyObject?

                currentData.value = post

                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                onError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            if let dict = snapshot?.value as? [String: Any] {
                let post = Post.transformPostPhoto(dict: dict, key: snapshot!.key)
                onSucess(post)
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpFKa.png)

I do not know how to add a picture directly. Sorry

Comment: `Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid` Apparently, that's not an optional, so an `if let someLetName = someNonOptionalVar` should throws that error. I think you meant `let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`, because the user might not be set and that's what could crash (and what you are avoiding with the unwrapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid returns a String, not String?. If you want to perform a conditional check, you should use

```
if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
     //Logic here
}
```

If you want to assign value of Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid to uid, you should do it elsewhere, not inside an if statement

Answer (score 0):

The `let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid` part of your `if-let/var` statement returns a `String` instead of an `String?`. You're force unwrapping `currentUser` Change it to `currentUser?.uid`